# Getting count of total messages in a subscription client that is taking messages from azure topics

Tags: node.js, azureservicebus

I am using this code :

```
 var ServiceBusClient = require('azure-service-bus-client');
 var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(
 {
    serviceBusConnection: ""
  }
);

(function(){
   serviceBusClient.receiveSubscriptionMessage(topicName, subscriptionName, 
     function (err, message) {
       console.log("message body :", message);
    });

 })();
```

I am searching for a particular message body, for which I am thinking to iterate the above method - receiveSubscriptionMessage() but for this I need the count of total messages in a subscription client.

I am looking for node.js code, many places on internet they have given in JAVA or c# but for count I cannot find MessageCount. Any help will be fine.

Link to the libraray I am using is : https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-service-bus-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a late reply, but the library mentioned in the post is not maintained by Microsoft or Azure.

The latest version 7.0.0 of `@azure/service-bus` offers `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` that lets you manage the service-bus resources.

For the problem in this question, you can leverage the `getSubscriptionRuntimeProperties` method to get the count of messages in the subscription.

Here is an example on using `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` - [administrationClient.ts](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/typescript/src/advanced/administrationClient.ts)

In case someone is running into issues with the older service-bus SDK for node and landed here, refer to the links below.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)

Answer (score 0):

The total count is not possible to fetch, until and unless we have the command over the sender.

So, the other workaround that I was able to figure out was only after receiving and checking every message for the specific pattern/condition required.